# How to setup uploaded file's path in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to have uploaded file to be stored in my specified folder like this:

```
/SpringMVC/tmp
```

[image]

but it is stored into this folder:

```
C:\Users\zhanzhex\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\SpringMVC\tmp\spittr\uploads
```

this is my controller method for processing uploading:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/register", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String processRegistration(
        @RequestPart(name="profilePicture",required=false) Part profilePicture,
        @Valid Spitter spitter, Errors errors) throws IOException
{
    if (errors.hasErrors())
    {
        System.out.println("find errors");
        return "registerForm";
    }
    profilePicture.write(spitter.getId() + "_profile." + profilePicture.getSubmittedFileName().substring(profilePicture.getSubmittedFileName().indexOf(".") + 1));
    spitterRespository.saveSpitter(spitter);
    return "redirect:/spitter/"+spitter.getId();
}
```

I just configure the temp folder for file upload (`/tmp/spittr/uploads`) in my `web.xml`, but I want to change the folder while calling write method within controller method, seems I can't. if I calling the write method like this:

```
profilePicture.write("/tmp/spittr/uploads/" + spitter.getId() + "_profile.jpg");
```

it will throw IOException to indicate that the folder is not existing:

```
C:\Users\zhanzhex\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\SpringMVC\tmp\spittr\uploads\tmp\spittr\uploads
```

so, I have to remove prefix "/tmp/spittr/uploads" when I calling profilePicture.write method.

see my **web.xml** below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SpringMVCs</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>spittr.config.RootConfig</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spittrAppServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>spittr.config.WebConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <multipart-config>
        <location>/tmp/spittr/uploads</location>
        <max-file-size>2097152</max-file-size>
        <max-request-size>4194304</max-request-size>
    </multipart-config>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spittrAppServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

I don't know why, can I change the destination folder setting? How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Part you can use MultipartFile or FilePart interfaces

```
@RequestPart(name="profilePicture",required=false) MultipartFile profilePicture
```

These interfaces expose .transferTo() function to copy data to file that you can use like

```
profilePicture.transferTo(new File("/path/to/file"));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, seems "transferTo" method works as same as "write" method, I think I need another way to figure it out

Comment: It should have worked because you are passing a File object created with absolute path. Then, I would suggest use .getInputStream() function from MultipartFile interface and copy the data from the inputStream to destination file of your choice.

Comment: yes, actually I use this method, it works fine, but can you please see my another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47564838/cannot-find-webapp-published-by-eclipse-in-tomcats-webapps-folder 
I'm not sure this problem is related to that issue described.