# Cannot find webapp published by eclipse in tomcat's webapps folder

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I created a spring web app project in Eclipse, I can start the webapp from Eclipse and it will show the webpage correctly, but if I type following URL, it reports 404 error:

see below:

[image]

but type the URL like this is fine:

[image]

and I remember that I should find my web application "SpringMVC" in this folder:

```
%HOME%\apache-tomcat-8.5.23\webapps
```

but I can't see it, I don't know where is my project deployed by eclipse.
so, can someone help me explain the reason, is there any configuration I need to do? what is the default folder the web application will be deployed to ?

Comment: See my updates.

Answer (score 1):

1. Clearly your application has been deployed with context **SpringMVC**. Therefore, you need to access your application with url **localhost:8080/SpringMVC** in your browser instead of localhost:8080.
2. When you run your application from Eclipse it is deployed in directory  **.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps** in your workspace directory. There may be some changes in the path depending on the version of eclipse. But try to find ***server.core** in **./matadata/.plugins** directory.

**Update**

3. When you run Dynamic WebApplication from eclipse, it will deploy your project to tomcat as a war with default context root as your project name. To change the context root right click on your project, go to **properties -> Web Project Settings**. Here you can change the context root. Note - you will need to stop the server, clean, publish and then start the server again to make the change into effect.

Comment: I mean I want to see Tomcat welcome page by typing http://localhost:8080, but right now is 404 error, I want to know what's the problem

Comment: What kind of project have you created in your eclipse DynamicWebApplication or EnterpriseApp or MavenProject or ...??

Comment: I created Dynamic WebApplication project

Answer (score 0):

Check the tomcat status from your terminal (CTRL-ALT-T from ubuntu) then
sudo systemctl status tomcat
Eclipse is starting/stopping the tomcat server during project testing so i guess you do not have the tomcat running when you try to access the localhost:8080